# Interactive IDE API for learning

Tags: ide, api, educational

I want to create an application (preferably web) that someone can learn some programming concepts. Similar to [Try Ruby](http://tryruby.org/levels/1/challenges/0), the IDE will compute to see if your answer is correct. It would just have lessons with questions and expected answers. Is there an API that exists with this? It should allow multiple different languages (C#, Java, JavaScript, HTML, CSS, SQL, etc).

I apologize if this is too vague of a description.